# Synthesizing only what is needed is a good memory management practice?

Tags: objective-c

I'm creating a custom view class that has more than 1 styles. Which means that some properties might be initialized sometimes while some others might not be. Is it wise to synthesize only the properties that will be used every time?

For example:

This are the properties that it contains:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSUInteger style;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIImageView *imageView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) UILabel *descriptionLabel;
- (id)initWithStyle:(NSUInteger)style;
```

If the style is **StyleDefault** then all of the above will be initialized and used. If the style is **StyleMinimal** only the imageView will be initialized and used.

Is it a good memory management practice to synthesize only the imageView?

Answer (score 2):

I think you misunderstand the nature of synthesized properties.

Declaring the property doesn't create the memory for that property, you do that yourself. Synthesizing just sets up the KVC setters and getters - and with the modern versions of Xcode you don't even need to do that.

So, in your question - it makes no difference to the memory use of your app whether you synthesize properties that may or may not be used.

Answer (score 1):

The recent compiler versions will synthesize your properties automatically. They should all be initialized with nil values, so just keep that in mind when trying to access those properties in your code.

Comment: Which means that i really don't need to synthesize anything at all, right? Since they are synthesized automatically.

Comment: Correct, and also the 'retain' keyword is no longer used for ARC code. You want to use either 'strong' or 'weak' in your property declarations.

Comment: I understand what is the difference between strong an weak but can you make an example on where to use them?

Comment: The answer to that question can be pretty lengthy. I would suggest doing a search on SO to research the differences between the two keywords and when it's appropriate to use each one!

Answer (score 0):

**If you have created property (XCode4.3 compilers and below) then you should synthesize it, otherwise you will get warning messages.**

And in XCode4.4+ compilers you need not to synthesize explicitly, compiler does for you. So you can not do anything there

Comment: You don't have to synthesize properties. The modern LLVM compiler will do auto-synthesize for you, or you can write your own setters and getters which will not cause a warning.

Comment: @Abizern: yes you are right, i update my answer, is it OK now?